# Returning a function's values in a class

Tags: git, python-3.x

I have a script where I'm trying to create a class to encapsulate a user name and pswd for GitHub authentication and to build the repository object.

I'm creating the class as I would like to use the credentials and user variable (to build the repo) in another script.

I have tried to return the value to the function, but I get an error message.  The two error messages I get are attributeerror and variable not defined.

My syntax is not right, but I can't figure out where I'm getting it wrong.

I've tried different variations and still can't get it to work.

I think I need to return the results of the function to the `gh` and `user` variables and then use the function as such: `result = myobjectx.function().repository(myobjectx.function().user, repo).pull_requests('open')`.  I followed the tutorial located here: http://www.learnpython.org/en/Classes_and_Objects

I've tried this variation and it's still not working and I think it's because all that is doing is prompting for the credentials again and it's not seeing the user variable??

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import os
import github3
from github3 import login, GitHub, authorize
from getpass import getuser, getpass
import requests
import csv
import configparser
import sys
import datetime
import codecs

sys.__stdout__ = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)



# Class to authenticate to GitHub
class GitAuth:

    def function(self):
        try:
            import readline
        except ImportError:
            pass

        try:
            user = input('GitHub username: ')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            user = getuser()

        password = getpass('GitHub token for {0}: '.format(user))


        gh = login(user, password)

myobjectx = GitAuth()

myobjectx.function()

# read the contents of the config file to pull in the repo name
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('repo.ini')
repo = config.get('repos', 'repo1')

result = myobjectx.gh.repository(user, repo).pull_requests('open')


def list_all_prs():
    # open csv file and create header rows

    with open('c:\\pull.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
        csv_writer.writerow(['Id', 'Login', 'Title', 'Commits', 'Changed Files'])

    # iterate through repo for pull requests based on criteria and output to csv file
    for pr in result:
        data = pr.as_dict()
        changes = (mybojectx.gh.repository(myobjectx.user, repo).pull_request(data['number'])).as_dict()
        # keep print to console statement for testing purposes
        # print(changes['id'], changes['user']['login'], changes['title'], changes['commits'], changes['changed_files'])


        with open('c:\\pull.csv','a+',newline='') as f:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

            csv_writer.writerow([changes['id'], changes['user']['login'], changes['title'], changes['commits'],
                                 changes['changed_files']])


list_all_prs()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "authent_test.py", line 48, in <module>
    result = myobjectx.gh.repository(user, repo).pull_requests('open')
AttributeError: 'GitAuth' object has no attribute 'gh'
```

repo.ini:

```
[repos]
repo1 = some-repo
```

Comment: Can you include the actual error tracebacks in your question, and an example of repo.ini , so that we can attempt to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @ChrisGuest  Updated.  Please note that this one of the traceback error messages as I've been modifying the script and closed several windows :).  Also, I added the ini, but changed the repo name for security issues.

Comment: With the above traceback: you should assign `gh = ...` as `self.gh = ...` for what you want. That, or return `gh` from `function()`.

Comment: `function` is a bad name, even more so since it's actually a method. How about `authenticate`?

Comment: @Evert  I agree, but I was following the tutorial and tried to stick with what they had (still a newbie).  I'm going to try your proposed solution and get back to you and thread with results.  Thanks!

Comment: I modified the code as you stated, but now I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "authent_test.py", line 45, in <module>
    result = myobjectx.gh.repository(myobjectx.user, repo).pull_requests('open')
AttributeError: 'GitAuth' object has no attribute 'user'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that `gh` is defined within a method and is not an attribute of GitAuth.

The second problem is user is defined within the class, but is called here:

```
result = myobjectx.gh.repository(user, repo).pull_requests('open')
```

So `user` will be undefined at that point.

```
class GitAuth:
    gh = None
    def function(self):
        try:
            user = input('GitHub username: ')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            user = getuser()

        password = getpass('GitHub token for {0}: '.format(user))
        self.gh = login(user, password)
        return user

myobjectx = GitAuth()
user = myobjectx.function()
```

I also don't understand why this block of code was there. It didn't appear to do anything:

```
    try:
        import readline
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

Comment: @ChrisGuest...this worked perfectly, thanks!!  I also removed that line of code.